# Group Function based on two different Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having one order table which is containing the orders.

Each order is having specific cost related to it and also status of the order.

So i need 4 columns in the output.

1st will show count of the records having status id as 1 & 2.
2nd will show sum of cost of the records having status id as 1 & 2
3rd will show count of the records having status id not in  1 & 2.
4th will show sum of cost of the records having status id not in 1 & 2.

I am not getting the approach how to fix such issue so that i don't need to hit the database many times.Any solution

Comment: Maybe I see your table and your result?

Comment: Its simple.I can't share the table structure due to security

Comment: then make an imaginary table so we can show you.  If it's simple you should be able to find the answer with a simple google search

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I have a simple example for your case.
You could use `SUM` and `CASE WHEN` to achieve it.
Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Id int IDENTITY (1,1),
    StatusId int,
    Cost decimal(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    --Id - this column value is auto-generated
    StatusId,
    Cost
)
VALUES
(1, 10),(2, 10),(3, 20), (4, 20),
(1, 10),(2, 10),(3, 20), (4, 20),
(1, 10),(2, 10),(3, 20), (4, 20)

SELECT 
       sum(CASE WHEN sd.StatusId IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCount_1_2, 
       sum(CASE WHEN sd.StatusId IN (1,2) THEN sd.Cost ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCost_1_2,
       sum(CASE WHEN sd.StatusId NOT IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCount_Not_in_1_2,
       sum(CASE WHEN sd.StatusId NOT IN (1,2) THEN sd.Cost ELSE 0 END) TotalCost_Not_in_1_2
FROM @SampleData sd
```

Returns

```
TotalCount_1_2  TotalCost_1_2   TotalCount_Not_in_1_2   TotalCost_Not_in_1_2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6               60.00           6                       120.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this.

```
SELECT COUNT(f1)  AS Col1
,SUM(f1)          AS Col2
,(SELECT COUNT(f1) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t1.id1 <> t2.id1 OR t1.id2 <> t2.id2) AS Col3
,(SELECT SUM(f1) FROM yourTable t3 WHERE t1.id1 <> t3.id1 OR t1.id2 <> t3.id2) AS Col4
FROM yourTable t1
GROUP BY id1,id2
```